# Discord.js users without avatars crash the bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Hello I have a very serious problem, if someone uses commands in my bot his avatar shows up but people who do not have an avatar after using the command crash the bot because the bot can not send their avatar which causes errors, I hope this is enough code (it is a footer with embed)

`${message.author.avatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true })}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `User#displayAvatarURL()` instead, This will handle default avatars instead of throwing an error.

```
message.author.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true })
```